# Inserting blade code in blade code

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a button with the Form builder

```
{!! Form::button('<span style="color: {!! $colour[$i] !!}" class..') !!}
```

The rest of the contents of the button are irrelevant, what I was trying to do was make the colour of the font `$colour[$id]` which worked fine when I tested it in raw HTML, but it keeps exiting the quotes when I add blade inside another blade function.

I guess I can't do that, how would I be able to use php in blade code without exiting the function? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an array with your style to this method, like:

```
Form::button(['style' => 'yourstyle']);
```

Comment: I do, but this styling is for the span within the button itself